# How Do I remove minimize, maximize, and close buttons in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, window-manager, titlebar, window-buttons

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. Previously in GNOME 3, the minimize, maximize, and close buttons never appeared on any of my applications, such as Chromium Browser and Emacs. These buttons annoy me because I am used to  clicking <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

How do I remove these buttons from Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get rid of those window control buttons from *all* the windows run the following command in Terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :
```

To undo this step, run

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

Comment: Awesome it works! I was wondering how you found out about this command?

Comment: `gsettings list-schemas` and then `gsettings monitor <schema>` while you tweak gnome settings with a UI tool such as `Tweaks`